# Why don't functions have a [[Value]] attribute?

Tags: javascript

It seems that functions are missing the [[Value]] attribute property which is present on other object properties:

```
function a() {
  console.log('Hello World');
}

var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'a');

// descriptor contains:

Object {writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
```

Compared to:

```
var person = {
  age: 1
};

var descriptor2 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, 'age');

// descriptor2 contains:

Object {value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

Why isn't there a [[Value]] attribute like most regular object properties? I would expect it would contain the actual function body code but it looks like it doesn't ever exist for functions?

Comment: The source code of the function as string, i guess ?

Comment: Did you expand the descriptor in the console?

Comment: I get `Object { value: a(), writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the value of the property is a function or a number doesn't really matter to the descriptor / property. And the descriptor does have a `value` property:
[image]

How the console works is not standardized, so why something is or isn't displayed is implementation dependent.

Do not blindly trust the console, verify your assumptions with code.

Comment: Thanks - console.dir() showed the value attr for me: http://www.i.imgur.com/1PF46GO.jpg

Comment: Might have something to do with the new scoping rules in ES6, and `window.a` not even being the function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use a browser which hides the value for some nonsense reason. Just use another one with better devtools.

Even the so simple stack snippet console shows the value properly:

```js
function a() {
  console.log('Hello World');
}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'a'));
```